# Unwanted symbols while pasting text on to terminal

Tags: command-line, copy, paste, xfce4-terminal

I get 0~ symbol before the text and 1~ after the text while pasting it on to the terminal window.

Is it related to some edits that I made in .bashrc or .vimrc files?

Eg: I see '0~allowed1~' when I press ctrl+shift+v while pasting the text 'allowed'

Comment: I don't see how the edits could be relevant but we can't know since you don't show us what you did. Please [edit] your question and give us more details. What exactly did you change in `.bashrc`? How are you copying (ctrl+C? simple selection? a clipboard manager?)? What are you copying from? Does it also happen if you paste into `xterm` or any other terminal? Run `cat >> file.foo` then paste the text, hit Ctrl+C and then run `cat file.foo | od -c` and add the output to your question. That will show us what characters are actually being pasted.

Comment: Sounds like you've enabled *bracketed paste mode* - see for example [Copy-Paste in xfce4-terminal adds 0~ and 1~](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196098/copy-paste-in-xfce4-terminal-adds-0-and-1)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for the link. I was able to fix my issue. I did not add set t_BE= to my .vimrc file. That was causing this problem.

Comment: @terdon thank you for showing concern to my problem. I was able to solve it with steeldriver 's help

Comment: Great! Please post an answer explaining what you did to solve it so the question can be marked as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional way that this problem can manifest. Readline's `~/.inputrc` file can contain the following:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste On
```

This is not fixed by the above method and has eluded me for months. Removing this line or setting

```
set enable-bracketed-paste Off
```

will fix this nicely.

Consult the man page for readline for more information on this parameter and the `~/.inputrc` file since you can change the file's location with the INPUTRC environment variable

Comment: This also worked for me in various apps (e.g. less) running in a "terminator" terminal

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by adding set t_BE= to my .vimrc file. thanks for the help @terdon and @steeldriver.

[Copy-Paste in xfce4-terminal adds 0~ and 1~](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196098/copy-paste-in-xfce4-terminal-adds-0-and-1)